# Return query with nested lookup to associated table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables “subjects” and “subject_entries” and “entries”. subject_entries is an associated table containing “subject_id” and “entries_id” as below

> subject_id | entry_id
>
> ```
>  2     |     36 
>  3     |     33 
>  4     |     36
> ```

I would like to run a query on the subjects table, but with a Boolean argument (true = yes) if the subject exists the subject_entries table, for a given entry_id. For example, if subject_entries.entry_id = 36 I would see

> subject_id | entry_id
>
> ```
>  2     |    true 
>  3     |     
>  4     |    true
> ```

If the subject_entries.entry_id = 22 I would see

> subject_id | entry_id
>
> ```
>  2     |     
>  3     |    true 
>  4     |
> ```

I'd appreciate any comments on how I should go about achieving this

Comment: subject_entries.entry_id = 22  OR subject_entries.entry_id = 33 ?

Comment: That returns only those matching values. I would like all lines with the boolean giving appropriate value per line (so it's like a full summary rather than filtered list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN subject_entries.entry_id = 36 
THEN subject_entries.entry_id = TRUE ELSE NULL END as entry_id
FROM subject_entries
```